# Roblox - For loop not running with number type variables even if it is above 0

Tags: roblox, luau

To clarify the question title, I have a `for` *loop* that runs an amount of time depending on the number variable value that is above 0. So instead of creating a variable that the value is on a method returned value, I just put the method but same result, it still doesn't work.

I searched on Google but it was with `while` loops and not `for` loops (even if the title contains *for loop* or it is just a mistake because they didn't use `#` before or anything like that). The code is very simple as you can see:

```
if getItemNumber() > 0 then

    local numb = 0 --This will be the price after the loop
    local loopNumb = getItemNumber()

    for i=10, loopNumb, 10 do --I start with i=10 and it executes for each items and increments by 10 everytime so it will add the loopNumb number times 10 for the price because 1 item = 10 money. (sorry for being difficult to understand)
        print(i) --I need to print to check if the loop executes, it does not.
        numb += loopNumb * 10
    end

    print(numb)
    --more code but not related to the problem and I need this loop for the code after.
end
```

**If you need to see the `getItemNumber()` function, look at this code:**

```
function getItemNumber() : number
    local currString = script.Parent.Parent.NumberOfItemsTxt.Text
    local currNumb = tonumber(currString)

    if currNumb ~= nil then
        print("valid")
        return currNumb
    else
        print("nil")
        return 0
    end
end
```

I tried replacing `loopNumb` by the method directly but it still does not run. Did I miss something or is it a bug?

**Note: the loop is not a nested loop and it is inside a click event on a gui element (TextButton) in a LocalScript**

Comment: When you run your code, what does `getItemNumber()` give you?

Comment: For example if I type 2 (or 3 etc...) of these items, I get the number that I typed when I click the buy button and I get returned 2 (or 3 etc...) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you pass to a for-loop instruct the loop where to start and where to end.

The first number is the starting point. The second is the ending point, and the third is how large of a step you take to get there.

For example :

```lua
for i=1, 10, 2 do
```

The variable `i` will start at 1, and then every loop will add 2 until `i` is greater or equal to 10. So : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, done.

In your code, you've said that you are passing in values like 2 and 3 which end up being equivalent to :

```lua
for i=10, 2, 10 do
```

... start at 10, and in steps of 10 at a time, please loop until you are at 2. Since `i` is already beyond the end limit, your loop exits immediately and does not run.

It's unclear from your code what you want to happen, but try reducing the numbers to just the number of times you want it to loop.

```lua
for i = 1, loopNumb, 1 do
```

Comment: It worked, the loop runned. I am always so stupid :| ... Because before I used `i` for changing a value but I realised that it was useless, the second number was always 30 because before the player needs to buy 30 items at a time and I forgot to change the ì`value :)